# Importing ECO data from bloomberg into excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I am trying to import data from Bloomberg into Excel using VBA.

Currently I'm manually pulling data from BBG by searching 'ECO' and customize my filters(date) and columns. Is there any way I can automate this process (with filter on dates and customized columns)?

A sample code will be greatly appreciated! Thanks:)

Comment: There are plenty of examples online of importing from Bloomberg to Excel - did you try searching Google? I'm afraid your question is a bit too broad for us to help you...

Comment: I'm not sure you can import ECO data into Excel - have you tried to ask the Bloomberg help desk (F1 F1 on your terminal)?